# Windows 7 vs. Windows Server 2008 for a development machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, development-environment

I finally got some time on my hand to upgrade my main dev. machine from Windows XP SP3. Right now I have licenses to both Windows 7 Enterprise Edition and Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition.

I mainly do web development (ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, RIAs .. etc)

Which is a better option for a 24/7 active development machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop on Windows 7 machine for Windows 2008 because they both have IIS7.5 installed on them.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 7 for the development, then create a Server2008 VM on that (or deploy to a real box if you've got one) to use as a test server so that you can test deployment of your app and see your app function from both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 would be fine. Windows 2008 would look heavy a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What application kind do you develop?

For some applications, like Sharepoint, you'll need a Windows 2008 box.

Comment: web development (ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, RIAs .. etc)

Comment: in this case, a Windows 7 box will be fine